# passing argument makes pointer from integer without a cast calling from printf

Tags: java, c, pointers, compilation, integer

This is probably a really easy question but I don't understand how characters in C work since I'm so used to Java, but I have this code:

```
char c = 'C';
printf(char2int(c));
```

which points to a function in another file:

```
int char2int(char digit){}
```

But I get this error when compiling:

> passing argument 1 of 'char2int' makes pointer from integer without a
>   cast [enabled by default]

Comment: Post original code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

You can't print integers like this in C. Also, I'm assuming you try to get ASCII code of the char, you can get it just by casting. Try something like this:

```
int char2int(char digit)
{
    return (int)digit;
}

void main()
{
    printf("%d", char2int('c'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also the prints function prints a format, it should read something like
`printf("%d\n",char2int(c));`

`"%d"` prints an argument of type `int`
`"\n"` is newline

It's best to use gcc's warnings to detect format errors, use -Wformat or -Wall as compiler options

Answer (score 0):

Characters and integers in C are almost the same,that is each character have an integer number depending on [ASCII character set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Table_ascii_extended.png).So if you have `int a=67` you can use it in an `printf` like `printf("%c",a)`,although a is an int,and you can do vice verse.

But about your code I should say I tried your code and it works correctly if you correct your mistake in using `printf`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int char2int(char c)
{}

int main()
{
    char c='C';
    printf("%d",char2int(c));//printf must have at least 2 arguments to work correctly
}
```

if you try this code you will have 67 as input which is ASCII code for 'C';(But don't forget ASCII character set is limited and each number is not a char :)  )

Comment: "each character have an integer number depending on ASCII character set."  --> ASCII is certainly the most popular character set used, but C does not specify ASCII usage.  Other non-ASCII characters sets have been used as well as various ASCII extensions.  `C` is not always 67.